# incompatible argument warning in sscanf() function

Tags: c

Getting this error when performing make:

```
$ make
cc -O2 -g src/bittwist.c -o src/bittwist -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lpcap
cc -O2 -g src/bittwiste.c -o src/bittwiste -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lpcap
src/bittwiste.c: In function ‘main’:
src/bittwiste.c:99:21: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int *’, but argument 3 has type ‘u_char *’ [-Wformat=]
                     sscanf(optarg, "%02x", &payload_opt[i]);
                     ^
```

Here is the code:

```
payload_len_opt = (u_short)c / 2; / possible resizing in editing functions /
payload_opt = (u_char *)malloc(sizeof(u_char) *payload_len_opt);
if (payload_opt == NULL)
error("malloc(): cannot allocate memory for payload_opt"); / make a byte of data from every 2 characters of optarg /
for (i = 0; i < payload_len_opt; i++) {
/ ugly - let me know if there is a better way to achieve this /
sscanf(optarg, "%02x", &payload_opt[i]);
```

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

Comment: The error message is quite self-explanatory. I suggest to compile with `make CFLAGS='-O2 -Wall -g'`

Comment: You need to post your `typedef`s.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - waht do those flags mean, can you add a short comment?

Comment: Read documentations of [make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/) and of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). `CFLAGS` is the conventional flags passed to the C compiler, and `-O2 -Wall -g` ask for optimization, almost all warnings, and debug info

Answer (score 3):

First, in your code

```
payload_opt = (u_char )malloc(sizeof(u_char)  payload_len_opt);
```

looks very wrong, because

1. Standard Warning : Please [do not cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`. If `u_char` is not of a pointer type, you're into deep trouble. So, better, don't cast at all. It is not at all required.
2. Even in case, your `u_char` is a pointer type, maybe a typedef to `unsigned char *`, you're missing a multiplication (`*`) operator there. in `c`, `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be `1`, so you can just write

   ```
   payload_opt = malloc(payload_len_opt);
   ```
3. The multiline comment syntax is `/*...*/`, not `/  ...  /` (missing `*`)

That said, regarding the error message, for `%x` format specifier, from `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.2

> ....The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to
>   unsigned integer.

but in your case, from the error message, it looks like `payload_opt` is of type `u_char *`.

Comment: I'm guessing some sort of copy-and paste error change it from `(u_char *)malloc(sizeof(u_char) * payload_len_opt);`

Comment: @MindaugasBernatavičius Nevertheless, don't cast. Also, check for comments, too.

Comment: @MattMcNabb But sir, IMHO, removing the casting removes these side-effects , too, isn't it? :-)